# Digitally filtered data in Arduino truncates range of values in the output

Tags: arduino, filtering, signal-processing

I have a 3rd order digital FIR filter implementation for an vibration detector project.
I used a hamming window, low pass filter. I wanted to try a lower order before I implemented a higher order filter.
This is my function for implementing the filter transfer function(code shown below)

```
float filter[] = {0.02421845531650103, 0.59999999999999998, 0.02421845531650103};
float fir(float input[] , int n ){
  int k=3;
  float output=0;

    output = filter[0] * input[k-2]+ filter[1] * input[k-1] + filter[2]*input[k]; 

//  Serial.println(output);
  return output;

}
```

My inputs (potentiometer values) are mapped from 0 to 1023. However after filtering, the range of the outputs is now 0- 663 (approx). This is not what I intended. I expected a constant output of 1023 if the inputs are all 1023 and no change in the range of values.
I was going to use the map function to map the values back to 0 to 1023 but I'm not sure that is the correct way to go about it. Is there something wrong with the way I implement the filtering? Is this the normal behavior for the outputs to be truncated?

Any help available will be much appreciated.

Comment: `1024* (0.02421845531650103+ 0.59999999999999998+ 0.02421845531650103) = 663.99939648819408896`

Comment: I suggest you get some basic maths right befor you attempt to implement "high order filters". how can you expect 1023 as the weighted sum of 1023s if your weights don't add up to 1?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, the steady state output of an FIR filter will be a constant input of 1 will be equal to the sum of the filter coefficients. So, to get a steady state output value equal to the input, the sum of the filter coefficients has to be equal to 1.

To get filter coefficients summing up to 1, you should divide all coefficient by their sum `0.64843691063300202` to get:

```
float filter[] = {0.03734897708530974, 0.92530204582938058, 0.03734897708530974};
```

With these normalized filter coefficients you should now get outputs in the 0-1023 range for inputs in that same 0-1023 range.

Also note that the filtering operation would usually require the function to make use of the input sample index (argument `n` to the `fir` function) and not the hardcoded value `k=3`.